# Converting integer values of SQLite database to string values in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I have a tableview consisting of 7 rows in it with values from Sunday to Saturday.  If I chose Sunday and save then 1 is entered in my database. If I chose "Sunday" and "Monday" then 1 and 2 is entered for that particular id. This is working properly.

Now I am trying to display a string value in my textlabel by comparing the integer value entered in the SQLite database; i.e. for a particular id, if 1 is entered in the database then in the textlabel "Sunday" should be displayed and if 1 and 2 is entered in the database then in the textlabel, "Sunday" and "Monday" should be displayed.

I have done the code for this but the problem is when I choose "Sunday" and "Monday", only "Monday" is getting displayed in the textlabel instead of both.  Another problem is the value is getting displayed in all cells.

this is my code where i am fetching values from database depending on id

```
-(void)selectDaysFromDatabase
{
    appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];
    sqlite3 *database;
    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.alarmdaysarray count]; i++) 
    {
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {


                NSString *query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select alarm_days from AlarmDays where alarm_id =%@",[appDelegate.alarmdaysarray objectAtIndex:i]];

        const char *sql = [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while ( sqlite3_step(selectstmt) ==SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                WEEKDAY_INTVALUE =[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0) ];
                [daydisplayarray addObject:WEEKDAY_INTVALUE];
                for(int i = 0;i<[daydisplayarray count];i++) 
                        { 
                            str_label =@"";
                            int val = [[daydisplayarray objectAtIndex:i]intValue];


                            if (val==0) {
                                NSString *str = @"SUN";
                                str_label = [str stringByAppendingString:@"SUN"];
                            }
                            if (val==1){
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"MON"];
                            }
                             if(val==2){
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"TUE"];

                            }
                            if(val==3)
                            {
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"WED"];

                            }
                            if(val==4)
                            {
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"THU"];

                            }
                            if(val==5) {
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"FRI"];

                            }
                            if(val==6)
                            {
                                str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"SAT"];

                            }



                    }


            }



        }


    else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    }
    }

}
```

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath i have wriiten this code to display in my cell

```
cell.mRepeatLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str_label];
```

//Here i am directly setting my str_label to my cell.So the problem is the value gets set on the cell irrespective of id.

Comment: @Rani where u alloc this daydisplayarray ?? and that WEEKDAY_INTVALUE comes ok or not tried with NSLog || printDescription

Comment: @AJPatel daydisplayarray is allocated in the class where i am displaying the string.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you call setString or setText, it'll replace the text in the ui element. If you need to append the string, eg Monday, you'll need to do something like

```
[uxTextField setString:[[uxTextField stringValue] stringByAppendingString:@" Monday"];
```

As for the value being updated in multiple cells, could you please confirm that your variables and outlets have a one to one mapping?

Answer (score 0):

`str_label =@"";` should be out of the loop... as it re-initializes it again to `@""`..

Comment: but ankit after taking str_label outside the loop crashes the app giving an error that[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x619c770

Answer (score 0):

`str_label =@"";` 
 must be above while loop..

Can you please help me understand the purpose of ForLoop inside while?

As you can do the same without for loop also since you are already in while loop.

Hence your while loop must be as followed

```
str_label =@"";

while ( sqlite3_step(selectstmt) ==SQLITE_ROW)
{
  WEEKDAY_INTVALUE =[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0) ];
  [daydisplayarray addObject:WEEKDAY_INTVALUE];
   int val = WEEKDAY_INTVALUE;

   if (val==0) {
      NSString *str = @"SUN";
      str_label = [str_label stringByAppendingString:@"SUN"];
   }
   if (val==1){
       str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"MON"];
   }
   if(val==2){
     str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"TUE"];
   }
   if(val==3)
   {
     str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"WED"];
   }
   if(val==4)
   {
     str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"THU"];
   }
   if(val==5) {
     str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"FRI"];
   }
   if(val==6)
   {
     str_label =[str_label stringByAppendingString:@"SAT"];
   }
}
```

Comment: actually i am looping inside my daydisplayarray where the days from the database is getting added to the array

Comment: but they are getting added in the same while loop.. either you remove the for loop like as i did.. or implement your foor loop outside while loop.. once adding in display array is done..

Comment: i have done as told but the problem is my value is not getting appended.i.e if in the database for a particular id say 1 and 2 is saved in database it should display sunday and monday in textlabel but it is displaying only monday,monday

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Get rid of that if (value == x) spagetti code. Use a static NSArray filled with NSString values for weekday names and use index to get correct day string. Non-compiling sample code:

```
- (NSString *)weekName:(NSUInteger *)index
{
static NSArray *nameArray = nil;
if (!nameArray) {
    nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"empty on purpose since you use 1 for Sunday",
                @"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday",
                @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday",
                nil];
}
return [nameArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Like everyone said, code 'str_label =@"";' seems resets string to @"" (empty) at every for loop. No point to append anything to empty string. The code looks weird, too many undefined (global) variables, but guess something like this might do:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
for (int i=0; i<[daydisplayarray count]; i++) 
{ 
    NSInteger index = [[daydisplayarray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    [a addObject:[self weekName:index]];
}
str_label = [a componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
if (!str_label) str_label = @"Nothing found!";
```

Btw value is displayed in every cell, because of you code in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'. Make sure you recycle cells, make sure you reset text values for recycled cells.

Comment: in the str_label , null is getting passed

Comment: Well, guess you should debug why it's null :) Anyway, changed weekName index to be positive and added check whether str_label exists. Btw str_label is still a mysterious global variable... Should not use global variables (without good reasons).